# Azure Devops-How to verify whether team has exists in an organization (Azure CLI or Azure Bash)

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azureshell

```
AzureOrganization="https://dev.azure.com/ExampleOrganization"
AzureProject="ExampleProject"
az devops configure -d organization= $AzureOrganization project=$AzureProject

read-r-p "Enter name of iteration" iteration
echo @ iterationname
```

If @ iteration exists in the organization project , then perfect
if @ iteration does not exist, print out this iteration does not exist in the project

```
read-r-p "Enter name of team in the organization that you want to link in the iteration " team
echo @ team
```

If @ team exists in the organization project , then perfect
if @ team does not exist,print out this team does not exist in the project

So how do I know whether the team or Iteration already existed in Azure Devops Organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if a team exists, you can use

```sh
team=`az devops team show --team myTeamName 2>/dev/null`

if [ "$team" = "" ]; then
  echo "Team does not exist"
else
  echo "Team exists"
fi
```

if the team exists, `$team` will have JSON in it, otherwise not.

To determine if an iteration exists, you can use

```sh
iteration=`az boards iteration project list --path "\\ProjectRoot\\Path\\To\\Your\\Iteration" 2>/dev/null`

if [ "$iteration" = "" ]; then
  echo "Iteration does not exist"
else
  echo "Iteration exists"
fi
```

Look at your project iteration structure for how to structure the query to the path. My iteration tree is 4 levels deep. Yours may not be. If the iteration exists, `$iteration` will have JSON in it, otherwise not.

The `2>/dev/null` suppresses the stderr output from the CLI when the iteration or team does not exist. `--only-show-errors` does not suppress this.

The `if` statements may vary from shell to shell (I use `zsh`), so if this does not work you may need to look at documentation for the shell you're using.

Comment: Thanks a lot--is there a true/false value that I can use in If statement so if team not exist, it printout not exist, if it is exist, it print out exist. I need something like true false to use in if statement

Comment: Check the update to my answer.

Comment: it said the path parameter is expcted to be absolute path. Do you have a way to get the path by query the iteration name? Thanks so much

Comment: For that, you might need to invoke `az boards iteration project list` without the `--path` parameter, and with an appropriate `--depth` parameter setting (look at the maximum depth of your iteration tree for this). From there, you would scan the output for the specific iteration name.

Comment: Thanks so much...I am very new to this stuff. I even don't know how to scan the output. For example, you get az boards iteration project list --depth 3.  Then, how do I find the childIteration exist or not. Example Child Iteration--ABC. how do I know ABC existed in the json file and Can I get ABC.path by query json?  I want to ask a new question. But because my question get downvote.. I cannot ask so, which makes me comment here.